# Why is my session variables erratic after publishing my application to my server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-variables

First of all, I know there are better ways to make password recovery, I know identity framework has an easier way of doing it. So I'm not interested in all that advice, I just want to get to the bottom of the problem.

Basically this code works when doing a password recovery on the web app, when I test it locally. After I publish it, it doesn't work 9/10 times, but for some reason it still works 1/10 times.

I've traced the problem to my session variables being null even though they are set, this seems to only happen when the code is live on the server, but it works fine locally.

Why are my session variables null most of the time on my webserver? But then once in a while, it works? I can't get to the bottom of it.

Here is my code:

```
    // Reset password view
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ResetPassword()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // Reset password ajax method, sends out an e-mail to confirm password reset.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public string ResetPassword(string email)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["tecrom"] == null)
        {
            var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Customer.ContactMail == email);
            if (user != null)
            {
                var token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                Session["resetuserid"] = user.Id;
                Session["resettitle"] = user.Customer.Title;
                Session["resetemail"] = email;
                Session["resettoken"] = token;
                var body = $"Kære {user.Customer.Title}<br><br>Vi har modtaget en anmodning om at genoprette dit password.<br><br>Bekræft venligst dit password reset ved at klikke <a href='https://pdfparser.dk/Home/FinishReset?hash=" + token + "'>her</a>, eller ignorer denne mail hvis du ikke ønsker at fortsætte.<br><br>Mvh x.dk";
                EmailHelper.SendMail(email, "Genopret dit password", body);
                var myCookie = new HttpCookie("tecrom");
                var now = DateTime.Now;

                // Set the cookie value.
                myCookie.Value = now.ToString();
                // Set the cookie expiration date.
                myCookie.Expires = now.AddMinutes(15);
                // Add the cookie.
                Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
                return "ok";
            }
            else
            {
                return "error";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "error2";
        }
      
    }

    // The final step in the password reset proces
    public ActionResult FinishReset(string hash)
    {
 
        var token = (string)Session["resettoken"];
 
        if (token == hash) 
        {
            var password = "Tempas" + new Random().Next(100000, 999999);
            var userid = (string)Session["resetuserid"];        
            var mail = (string)Session["resetemail"];
            var title = (string)Session["resettitle"];

            var um = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            ApplicationUser user = db.Users.Find(userid);             
            user.PasswordHash = um.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(password);
            db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
           
            var body = "Kære "+title+"<br><br>Dit midlertidige password er: "+password+ "<br><br>Log venligst ind på pdfparser.dk og skift dit password hurtigst muligt. Dette kan gøres i menuen oppe i højre hjørne af websitet efter du er logget ind.<br><br>Mvh x.dk";
          
            EmailHelper.SendMail(mail, "Dit midlertidige password", body);
            ViewBag.Message = "Et midlertidigt password er sendt til dig, tjek din mail for at fortsætte";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Noget er desværre gået galt, dit password forbliver uændret";
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Basically the reset password function checks the db for the user with that e-mail, then sends out a mail with a confirmation token saved in a session variable. When the user clicks the link in the sent out e-mail, it activates the finishreset function, which then creates a temporary password and sends it out to the user via e-mail.

Again I know this isn't the optimal way of doing it, but I'm kinda obsessed with finding out why my session variables are behaving weirdly on my server. Does anyone have a clue as to why it seems so random whether it works or not?

I will almost certainly need session variables in other places in my web app in the future, so I need to make sure they work and behave normally in general. Simply.com is where I have my server if that has any relevance.

Comment: Is the server a single server, or is it part of any kind of server farm of cloud infrastructure?  Web server session state doesn't scale horizontally.  Ideally any information each operation needs is either provided by the client or fetched from persisted data.

Comment: For cookies are they disabled on users machines so it is not saving them except they may be enabled on the 1 out of 10 successful ones you are seeing?

Comment: David: It's a typical .net webserver hosted on simply.com so it's not part of a server farm or structure. But the web application does have cron jobs running in the background using Quartz, if that has any relevance?

Comment: Brad: I'm not sure what you mean? I'm using a cookie to prevent spam in the same function so I think cookies are enabled as per normally, as far as I know?

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, it should work only when user open that reset password email link from same browser from where they click to Reset password request. Because session maintain within that browser only.

Comment: Well yeah I know that, that's not a problem. It still doesn't most of the time though.

Comment: Okay. there is a possibility of the SameSite Cookie Handling issue. Can you please configure following key in your web.config and try.  
`<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:SuppressSameSiteNone" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
 
  <system.web>
    <authentication>
      <forms cookieSameSite="None" />    
    </authentication>
    <sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>`

Comment: I tried those settings, it still has the same issue.